# Type conversion on the fly

Tags: amazon-athena

I've got CSV file (with aws billing info) where each field is stored as a string in quotes, like that: `"value"`

So part of the sample line looks as follows:

`"234234324223532","First 3 Dashboards per month are free.","2018-08-01 00:00:00","2018-08-01 01:00:00","0.0026881720"`

When I define new table as follows:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.mytable (
  Id INT,
  Desc STRING,
  StartTime TIMESTAMP,
  EndTime TIMESTAMP,
  Cost DOUBLE
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 's3://MYBUCKET/FOLDER/'`

I can only see `Desc` values in results of `Select * from mydb.mytable`

Is it possible to define some converters in `create table` statement?

Or do I need to remove most of the quotation marks (`"`) from source files? That's very undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is Athena is considering all content as string. If you define all columns as string you should be able to see all the content.

You can try using a Serde where you can define the quote char so the data types could be accepted:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.mytable (
  Id INT,
  Desc STRING,
  StartTime TIMESTAMP,
  EndTime TIMESTAMP,
  Cost DOUBLE
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"', 
  'separatorChar'=',') 
LOCATION 's3://MYBUCKET/FOLDER/'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it helped, however I stillhave problems with two `TIMESTAMP`'s fields, as I wrote in the question my date format is `2018-08-01 00:00:00`. I think this is default for Athena? When I try to select any timestamp field, error is thrown.

Comment: The error is `Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '2018-08-04 10:00:00' for field 14: For input string: "2018-08-04 10:00:00"

This query ran against the "mydb" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: ae932b9a-2e0a-4abc-a27b-db6886a516df.`

Comment: AWS Docs: OpenCSVSerde "Recognizes the TIMESTAMP type if it is specified in the UNIX format, such as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...], as the type LONG." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html I don't understand what I am doing wrong :-(

Comment: I see, this happens because the Serde output. OpenCSV serde, if you read the documentation, it says the output is going to be string. For example, if you read a timestamp using that serde, the output of that content is going to have the type string. It's a stupid thing this serde have, it doesn't respect your data type.

Comment: Said this, you have only two options:
1º: Pre-process the file in order to provide a better looking to Athena can read it with no problems,
2º: Define your timestamp as string and read it using specific casts.